# Retirar valor não numéricos de um dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, replace

[image: Data Frame]

Minha intenção é retirar os valores que aparecem com '......' conforme imagem acima e substituir por um campo vazio.

O código que estou usando para tentar remover é esse:

```
df['Energy Supply'].str.replace('[.]*', '')
```

contudo retorna um saída aonde todos os valores se tornam NaN

[image: Saída]

Como poderia consertar esse problema?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uma opção é usar a opção regex do replace: `df.replace('\.+', np.nan, regex=True)`

Segue exemplo replicável:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
                   'B': ['......', 6, '.......', 8, 9],
                   'C': ['........', 'b', 'c', '....', 'e']})

print(df.replace('\.+', np.nan, regex=True))
```

Resultado:

```
   A    B    C
0  0  NaN  NaN
1  1  6.0    b
2  2  NaN    c
3  3  8.0  NaN
4  4  9.0    e
```

Comment: Funcionou .... obrigado!

Comment: Se esta resposta resolveu o seu problema e não restou nenhuma dúvida, marque-a como correta/aceita ao clicar no "✅" que está abaixo do contador de votos da resposta, o que também marca a sua pergunta como resolvida.